# Get a response as xlsx using solrj in spring boot

Tags: solr, solrj

In an spring boot application, I am using solrj to query on solr 7.4. I want the output as `xlsx` file(not `csv`).

As mentioned [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/response-writers.html#xlsx-response-writer), I have added the required jars into the solr server classpath. Now when i hit `http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_name/select?q=*:*&wt=xlsx` in browser, I get a proper response from solr to download the result as a xlsx file.

**BUT**

***How can i achieve this using SOLRJ in a spring boot app?***

---

For other formats, like wt=xml/json/csv, solr response is a string which i can return from controller and set the content info in header to send it as a file. But i didn't get much info on how can i achieve it in case of xlsx file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured out a way. 
As per the [solr documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/response-writers.html#xlsx-response-writer), first copy the required jars into solr server classpath, then use the below code to get the response as xlsx file...

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
solrQuery.setQuery("add solr query");
solrQuery.addFilterQuery("add filter query");
solrQuery.setParam("wt", "xlsx");

QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest(solrQuery);
request.setMethod(METHOD.POST);
request.setResponseParser(new InputStreamResponseParser("xlsx"));

SolrClient client = // create solrClient
NamedList<Object> resp = client.request(request, collectionName);
InputStream xlsxStream = (InputStream) resp.get("stream");
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/xlsx/file");
IOUtils.copy(xlsxStream, output);
```